# Trying to understand effective addressing in x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, cpu-registers

I was asked the following question, but I don't see how it has enough information to be answered.

"If `EAX` contains `00000200H`, `EBX` contains `00000003H`, and the data segment contains `1000H`, what is the effective address generated by this instruction?"

```
MOV ECX,[ESI][EDI]
```

**How would I know what values were contained in the `ESI` and `EDI` registers?**  I know the `ESI` and `EDI` registers are typically used in string operations...

I also know the general format for creating effective addresses is:

1) Shift `DS` four bits to the left.

2) Add the shifted `DS` value to the offset value.

In the code snippet above, the offset is `[ESI][EDI]` which I believe is the same as `[ESI + EDI]`.  I interpret `[ESI][EDI]` to mean the following in English:

"The offset is equal to the value contained in the `ESI` register added to the value contained in the `EDI` register."

This is my first week in an 8-week x86 microprocessor course so I appreciate the feedback.

Comment: DSI?  There is no DSI register in an 80x86.

Comment: My previous comment referred to the original, unedited question. I've removed it to prevent further confusion.

Answer (score 1):

The effective address of `ds:eax+ebx` can be computed this way:

```
ds =  0x1000 (4096 in decimal)
eax = 0x200  (512 in decimal)
ebx = 3

ds:eax+ebx = 0x10 * 0x1000 + 0x200 + 3

ds:eax+ebx = 0x10203 (66051 decimal)
```

But nothing can be said about the value of `esi` and `edi` based on the values of `ds`, `eax` and `ebx`, as the registers are completely independent, so the effective address of `ds:esi+edi` cannot be computed neither.

Comment: If it's protected mode then from `data segment contains 1000H` we we can't tell what the segment base address is unless we're given the contents of the GDT.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze A good point. My answer is valid only for real mode.

Comment: I'm working in Real Mode.  I understand how you get DS:[EAX][EBX].  I think the original question is missing information because how would we know what [ESI] and [EDI] are without being told?

Comment: @JJBladester There's no way to deduce `esi` and/or `edi` from `ds`, `eax` and `ebx`. So the question you are asked is missing information.

Comment: @nrz I actually got a hold of the book's author.  You're right, the question was missing information.